# Realizar una prueba unitaria en NodeJs. Con mocha y chai;

Tags: nodejs, test, pruebas-unitarias, mocha, chai

Estoy realizando una prueba unitaria a una funcion, y lo que quiero es simular la comunicacion con el DTA(Que no se comunique con la base de datos); Por ejemplo: Esta es la funcion a la cual quiero realizarle la prueba...

```
public add(a, b): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.queueDta.add(a, b)
        .then(() => resolve({status: "created"}))
        .catch(() => reject({code: "QUE01"}));
    });
}
```

Y pues al realizar la prueba, quiero que la funcion add que esta conectada con el DTA, se ejecute pero de forma falsa y retorne true;
Cree un stub al DTA para modificar la función, pero los toma de forma diferente, por lo tanto, agrega la información a la base de datos.

```
context("addToQueue", () => {
    let data;
    it("ADD", async () => {
        const queueBns2 = new queueBns.QueueBns();
        const queueDta2 = new queueDta.QueueDta();
        let result2;

        data = sandbox.stub(queueDta2, "add").value(true);
        result2  = await queueBns2.add(1, 2);
          //-- Aca irian los expect, para validar la funcion ---
    });
});
```

Estaba buscando la manera de instanciar la clase de otra forma pero no sé, de que forma puedo modificar esa función y que el BNS utilice la función falsa. Gracias por su colaboración. Estoy pendiente :).

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la solucion y es la siguiente:

El archivo de mi prueba en este caso se llama

> QueueBns.spec.ts

Mis importaciones son:

```
declare var require: any;
import * as chai from "chai";
import "mocha";
import "reflect-metadata";

const sinon = require("sinon");
const expect = chai.expect;
let sandbox;
import * as sinonChai from "sinon-chai";
import { QueueBns, QueueDta } from "..";

const chaiIsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
chai.use(chaiIsPromised);
chai.use(sinonChai);
```

Y la prueba es la siguiente:

```
describe("QueueBns", () => {

afterEach(() => { sandbox.restore(); });

before(() => { sandbox = sinon.sandbox.create(); });

let instance2;

context("addToQueue", () => {
    let data;
    it("ADD", async () => {
        instance2 = new QueueBns();
        let result2;
        data = sandbox.stub(QueueDta.prototype, "add").resolves({nada: "Johan"});
        result2  = await instance2.add(1, 2);

        console.log("result2", result2); // El resultado es: {nada: "Johan"}
    });
});
```

});

> QueueBns.ts

```
import {injectable} from "inversify";
import {QueueDta} from "../data/QueueDta";
@injectable()
class QueueBns {
private queueDta: QueueDta;

constructor() {
    this.queueDta = new QueueDta();
}

public add(a, b): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.queueDta.add(a, b)
        .then((data) => resolve(data))
        .catch(() => reject({code: "QUE01"}));
    });
 }
}
export {QueueBns};
```

> QueueDta.ts

```
import { db } from "../../../app.config";
export class QueueDta {
    public add(a, b): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            db.collection("suma")
            .add({a, b})
            .then(() => resolve(true))
            .catch((error) => reject(error));
        });
    }
}
```

Como tal podemos observar en la prueba, que logramos modificar el resultado de la funcion add que se encuentra en QueueDta.ts

Espero les sirva si alguno se encuentra con el mismo problema :).